# How do you remove the dotted 'select' box on widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't know what the box is called but when I click a Radio button or select a tab a little dotted box shows around it. I want to remove this when they are selected, has anyone got any ideas?
I have tried searching it but its difficult when you don't know what the box is called.

[image: Example of what I am talking about]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This dashed box is here to show that the widget has the focus. When calling `style.element_option('focus')`, we can see that this element has two options: `focuscolor` and `focusthickness`. I have tried setting `focusthickness` to 0 but unfortunately it does not make the dashed box disappear. So the workaround I have found is to set `focuscolor` to the background color:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('TRadiobutton', focuscolor=style.lookup('TRadiobutton', 'background'))
```

If you want to apply this to all widgets, like checkbuttons, you can do instead

```
style.configure('.', focuscolor=style.lookup('.', 'background'))
```

so that the default color for the focus highlight will be the background color.

Comment: What does the '.' (dot) mean? does it just represent all widgets within that theme?

Comment: @Jacob Yes the dot means all widgets, more precisely this is the way to configure the default colors of the theme. Also, '.' is the name of the main window.